# CMake missing environment variables errors

Tags: cmake

I'm attempting to use cmake on Mac OSX i've installed both a binary version and then also from source. However i continue to receive the following errors when attempting to create a Makefile.

cpc1-dumb4-2-0-cust166:build bcrowhurst$ cmake .
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.

Missing variable is:

CMAKE_On_COMPILER_ENV_VAR

CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.

Missing variable is:

CMAKE_On_COMPILER

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/Users/bcrowhurst/NetBeansProjects/appon/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOnCompiler.cmake

CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:CMakeOnInformation.cmake

CMake Error: CMAKE_On_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

-- Boost version: 1.43.0

-- Found the following Boost libraries:

--   system

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

My CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )

project( Application On )

find_package( Boost COMPONENTS system REQUIRED )

link_directories( ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

    add_library( object ../source/object.cpp ../source/object.h )   
    target_link_libraries( object ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} )

endif()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2nd and later optional args to the PROJECT command should be known CMake language values.

It's typical values are:

- leave it off, don't provide a 2nd arg (default to C
  and CXX)
- C
- CXX
- Fortran
- NONE

You've provided "On" as a language value to the PROJECT command, which CMake does not know.

Remove the "On" and leave it blank or replace it with the languages you need for your project.

Comment: ding! What a pitfall, thats that name of my application "Application On". this worked cheers mate.

Comment: Thanks dude, I "named" my project `project(FFT Test Suite)`, or so I though. I have reinstalled CMake and stuff before finally finding this answer...